# When do I have to use aucPR instead of auROC? (and vice versa)

Tags: machine-learning, data-mining, cross-validation, model-evaluations

I'm wondering if sometimes, to validate a model, it's not better to use aucPR instead of aucROC? Do these cases only depend on the "domain  & business understanding" ?

Especially, I'm thinking about the "unbalanced class problem" where, it seems more logical to use the aucPR because recall and precision are well-used metrics for this problem.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yes, you are correct that the dominant difference between the area under the curve of a receiver operator characteristic curve ([ROC-AUC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Receiver_operating_characteristic)) and the area under the curve of a Precision-Recall curve ([PR-AUC](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/model_selection/plot_precision_recall.html)) lies in its tractability for unbalanced classes.  They are very similar and have been shown to contain essentially the same information, however PR curves are slightly more finicky, but a well drawn curve gives a more complete picture.  The issue with PR-AUC is that its difficult to interpolate between points in the PR curve and thus numerical integration to achieve an area under the curve becomes more difficult.

[Check out this discussion of the differences and similarities.](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~jdavis/davisgoadrichcamera2.pdf)

Quoting Davis' 2006 abstract:

> Receiver Operator Characteristic (ROC)
>   curves are commonly used to present results
>   for binary decision problems in machine
>   learning. However, when dealing
>   with highly skewed datasets, Precision-Recall
>   (PR) curves give a more informative picture
>   of an algorithm’s performance. We show that
>   a deep connection exists between ROC space
>   and PR space, such that a curve dominates
>   in ROC space if and only if it dominates
>   in PR space. A corollary is the notion of
>   an achievable PR curve, which has properties
>   much like the convex hull in ROC space;
>   we show an efficient algorithm for computing
>   this curve. Finally, we also note differences
>   in the two types of curves are significant for
>   algorithm design. For example, in PR space
>   it is incorrect to linearly interpolate between
>   points. Furthermore, algorithms that optimize
>   the area under the ROC curve are not
>   guaranteed to optimize the area under the
>   PR curve.

[This was also discussed on Kaggle recently.](https://www.kaggle.com/forums/f/15/kaggle-forum/t/7517/precision-recall-auc-vs-roc-auc-for-class-imbalance-problems/41179)

[There is also some useful discussion on Cross Validated.](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/7207/roc-vs-precision-and-recall-curves)

Comment: I also found [this 2015 NeurIPS paper by Peter Flach and Meelis Kull](https://papers.nips.cc/paper/2015/file/33e8075e9970de0cfea955afd4644bb2-Paper.pdf) quite useful on the subject.